# Is extern "C" on a c++ function allowed?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern “C”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

I am asking this because I'm writing a C++ program which uses a C library. This library has `foreach` functions that take a callback (naturally). Obviously, the library would call my callbacks as C functions.

First of all, **does this have anything to do with linkage of C vs C++?**

If it does, **is something like this valid and correct?**

```
extern "C" static bool callback(/*parameters*/)
{
    cout << "C++ thing inside the function" << endl;
    /* etc */
}
```

Comment: Good Read: [http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/c-calls-cpp.html](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/c-calls-cpp.html)

Comment: have you tried? what was the result?

Comment: @default, With gcc/g++, extern "C" seems to have no effect. But I'm looking for an answer by the standard.

Comment: @slavik262, I see. So it's absolutely unnecessary!